# htaccess RevriteEnngine url doesnt rewrite Why?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

in the same folder where there is `index.php` I have `.htaccess` file with the following code inside:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule  ^example.com/(.+)$ example.com/secondpage.php?firmname=$1 [R,L]
```

so that instead of

```
example.com/secondpage.php?firmname=GGGGGGG
```

it should show

```
example.com/GGGGGGG
```

but it doesn't work and I cant find mistake there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the hostname in the regex and rule's target. It's also showing the URL with the query string because you are using the `R` flag, which redirects the browser and thus changes the address in the location bar.

You probably want something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /secondpage.php?firmname=$1 [L]
```

And maybe:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+secondpage\.php\?firmname=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks, can you also say what to google to read about why this one works and mine didn't? I googled already and cant find explanation.